# Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have been trying to install the drawer in my project for a week. I have tested several combinations of versions between reanimated, gesture handler and react. I have redone the android studio installation and environment settings a few times but always get stuck on the same error:

What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ‘:react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]’.
[CXX1428] exception while building Json A problem occurred starting process ‘command ‘C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.22.1\bin\cmake.exe’’
```

I don’t know what else to do to solve this problem. I haven’t found the solution to this problem anywhere.

```
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.72.3",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^3.3.0",
```

More about the error:

```
Task :react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build\kotlin\sessions

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use ‘–warning-mode all’ to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings 93 actionable tasks: 88 executed, 5 up-to-date

info � Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ‘:react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]’.
[CXX1428] exception while building Json A problem occurred starting process ‘command ‘C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.22.1\bin\cmake.exe’’

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 2m 36s info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details. Done in 676.52s.
```

I don’t know what else to do to solve this problem. I haven’t found the solution to this problem anywhere.

```
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.72.3",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^3.3.0",
```

More about the error:

```
Task :react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build\kotlin\sessions

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use ‘–warning-mode all’ to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings 93 actionable tasks: 88 executed, 5 up-to-date

info � Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ‘:react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]’.
[CXX1428] exception while building Json A problem occurred starting process ‘command ‘C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.22.1\bin\cmake.exe’’

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 2m 36s info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details. Done in 676.52s.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved uninstalling cmake 3.22.1 and installing cmake 3.18.1